# Salesforce email sends using Reports or campaigns the tracking is not showing Report or campaigns name

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I used salesforce Campaigns and Reports from Guided sends in marketing cloud. The email have been sent successfully but when i look under Tracking ->My tracking ->overview summary. It's showing Api created dataextension(SalesForce-5598xxxe-3e8e-xxx-82ad-xxxxxx) instead of associated report or dataextension. Is some settings i am missing.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the v5 connector now named Marketing Cloud connector; and not  the legacy v2 connector. This is expected behavior with the new(er) Marketing Cloud Connector (anythng post v5).

Salesforce Sends automatically import the report data into a data extension prior to sending.   You also have the option to import the data from report ahead of time using an import activity and then configure your Salesforce Send to point to the imported "Salesforce Data Extension".

Comment: I am using v5 connector you are absolutely right it used to show the report or campaings name  in v2 connector. But we are using so many reports is they any way i can know which report or campain used under my tracking for org which used V5 connector.

Comment: no, I don't think so.